# Error while trying to apportable iOS app to Android

Tags: android, ios, compiler-errors, apportable

I have been trying to port my first iOS app to Android with apportable.
I have solved alot of warnings and errors but cannot get rid of this last one.
The App I made is a fitness application for jogging so it uses CoreLocation.
Everything looks good when I run apportable now except this last error:

Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.apptonix.easyrunner/testTabbedWithCore/libtestTabbedWithCore.a(DetailViewController.m.o):/Users/peterbodlund/Documents/xcodeprojects/Training/inlamning5/testTabbedWithCore/testTabbedWithCore/DetailViewController.m:function L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_114: error: undefined reference to 'OBJC_CLASS_$_MKPinAnnotationView'
scons: *** [Build/android-armeabi-debug/EasyRunner/apk/lib/armeabi/libverde.so] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pack'" in > ignored

Answer (score 2):

Usually this is an indicator that there were link errors.  Check your output higher up and look for missing symbol errors.

The build log is confusing because the build is parallel by default.

Add the option -j1 to cause the build to stop immediately after the first error.